# Multiple threads to load different grids attached to different set of collections retrieved from database

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, delegates, dispatcher

I have a wpf application created with MVVM design pattern. In a given view there are 5 grids all binding to a different set of collection, i.e 5 collections for 5 grids. Now i do not want to hang up the UI while the 5 sets of data are retrieved from the database.

Please let me know if the following solution is a good idea else please suggest one:

1. 5 observable collections for binding to the grids
2. 5 delegates calling `BeginInvoke` for the db operation and each will have `IEnumerable Collection<Type>` on `EndInvoke`.
3. The delegate oncomplete callback will populate the `ObservableCollection<Type>` from the `IEnumerable collection<Type>` to allow the dispatcher to update the UI from the UI thread as the begininvoke willwork on a threadpool thread.

Comment: Be prepared to chunk up those updates.  It won't matter if you multithread this if you are pummeling the UI with lots of updates.

Comment: @Will : right because only the one UI Thread which dequeue messages pipeline :)

Comment: @sll: Maybe after a couple iterations of WinRT updates we'll get more than one friggen UI thread.  Damn you, COM!

Comment: Interesting, how COM is involved in this case? Really have no such deep knowledge

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) component to simplify the process of moving work onto a background thread and then synchronizing back to the UI. Otherwise, your general approach sounds just find.

Comment: Is it (updating UI by multiple threads) makes sense at all since there is single UI Thread at all?

Comment: Will Dispatcher.BeginInvoke work for executing the long running database calls so that the UI thread does not get stuck up?

Comment: To be more precise will 5 calls to Dispatcher.BeginInvoke spawn up 5 threads from the thread pool??